# Trying to integrate gulp SASS with gulp Autoprefixer-postcss, failing miserably

Tags: gulp, autoprefixer, gulp-sourcemaps, gulp-ruby-sass

So, Autoprefixer has been bugging me to use the updated postcss version so I am trying to update my Gulp file.

The problem is all the examples do not integrate Sass as the first step; I use gulp-ruby-sass.

If I run my sass task on my sass directory (there are 2 scss files I need to process in there), this works and outputs 2 css files in the dest directory:

```
  gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return sass('./app/assets/sass')
  .on('error', function(err) {
    console.error('Error!', err.message);
  })
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/assets/css'))
  .pipe(reload({
    stream: true
  }));
});
```

But my question is how to integrate the next part, to pass the CSS through autoprefixer and generate sourcemaps? If I run this next in a sequence, this blows up with object is not a function errors:

```
  gulp.task('autoprefixer', function() {
  return gulp.src('./app/assets/css/')
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer({
    browsers: ['last 2 versions']
  })]))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/assets/css'));
});
```

I was trying to run them as a sequence, but would rather integrate them:

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  runSequence('sass', 'autoprefixer');
});
```

I just cannot put together the pipe that gets ruby-sass, autoprefixer, and sourcemaps to all work together.

**UPDATE:**

OK, even if I decide to keep the task separated (as suggested below by @patrick-kostjens), when I run the Autoprefixer task I get this error:

```
    [08:56:38] Starting 'autoprefixer'...

events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'toString' of null
at new Input (/Users/stevelombardi/github/designsystem/node_modules/gulp-postcss/node_modules/postcss/lib/input.js:29:24)
at Object.parse [as default] (/Users/stevelombardi/github/designsystem/node_modules/gulp-postcss/node_modules/postcss/lib/parse.js:17:17)
at new LazyResult (/Users/stevelombardi/github/designsystem/node_modules/gulp-postcss/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:54:42)
at Processor.process (/Users/stevelombardi/github/designsystem/node_modules/gulp-postcss/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:30:16)
at Transform.stream._transform (/Users/stevelombardi/github/designsystem/node_modules/gulp-postcss/index.js:44:8)
at Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:179:10)
at Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:167:12)
at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:223:10)
at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:213:5)
at Transform.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:180:11)
at write (/Users/stevelombardi/github/designsystem/node_modules/gulp-sourcemaps/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:623:24)
at flow (/Users/stevelombardi/github/designsystem/node_modules/gulp-sourcemaps/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:632:7)
at DestroyableTransform.pipeOnReadable (/Users/stevelombardi/github/designsystem/node_modules/gulp-sourcemaps/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:664:5)
at DestroyableTransform.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
at emitReadable_ (/Users/stevelombardi/github/designsystem/node_modules/gulp-sourcemaps/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:448:10)
at emitReadable (/Users/stevelombardi/github/designsystem/node_modules/gulp-sourcemaps/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:444:5)
```

And I tried autoprefixer = autoprefixer-core as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would make the `sass` task a dependency of `autoprefixer` by declaring the `autoprefixer` task as follows:

```
gulp.task('autoprefixer', ['sass'], function() {
    // Your current autoprefixer code here.
});
```

You can then simply run the `autoprefixer` task.

If you really want to integrate them into one task (even though the tasks do two separate things) you can try something like this:

```
gulp.task('autoprefixer', function() {
    return es.concat( 
        gulp.src('./app/assets/css/')
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer({
                browsers: ['last 2 versions']
            })]))
            .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        ,
        sass('./app/assets/sass')
            .on('error', function(err) {
                console.error('Error!', err.message);
             }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/assets/css'));
});
```

Do not forget to define `es` as `require('event-stream')`.

Answer (score 0):

How are you including the `autoprefixer` requirement? This doesn't work for me:

```
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
```

This does work:

```
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer-core');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try importing autoprefixer instead. I couldn't get gulp-autoprefixer working either and autoprefixer-core is now deprecated.

```
npm install autoprefixer --save-dev
```